# In France, is it possible to research at a postdoctoral level as a freelancer, not being on a regular contract?

Tags: mathematics, job-search, job, france

Perhaps this question is slightly out of scope for this page, but I still ask here.

Can you work for a **university/academic institution** as a researcher or as a teacher, with the **status of a freelancer**? In case this helps, I'm based in France and have applied for a **freelance status** (called *auto-entrepreneur/micro entrepreneur in the French administrative terms*), and even though I'm searching for regular temporary/permanent position in France, this hasn't seen any success yet, so I want to use that freelance status to do research at a high level (at least postdoctoral) as I strongly feel I'm genuinely passionate by fundamental research, so I've to find a way to do so, even if I may or may not be good enough to secure a formal position.

Just in case this helps: my subject(s) will be ideally the intersection between differential geometry and statistics/statistical machine learning, manifold learning, but open to other topics, e.g. applied differential geometry, or just statistical learning etc.

From my having spent long time in academia, I've never seen this happening, because normally the academic contracts are either regular CDD or CDI's. But I wonder if the above possibilities still exist in France or abroad?

EDIT: Some people asked me about my motivation for the same. It is my continued interest to do research and publish, but also to earn some money on the side by consulting or freelance jobs etc. IN fact once you're a freelance, you can hire other freelance to do your freelance projects not related to academia/research, so essentially some income without working, where I work on academic research projects myself. This is the reason I want my postdoc related contract to be a freelance once, where I can be employed as a consultant for a project.

Comment: "Freelancer" and employee are kind of opposites. How do you expect to be paid.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks for your comment. By 'freelance', I meant I'd charge for the number of hours I worked in a project, and not by a regular monthly amount of x€/month. So I'm imagining something like securing a project in say machine learning, with a faculty member who's a certain grant to hire researchers, but in place of hiring regular researchers, he can hire someone who'll bill him/the lab/department a certain amount that's a function of hours (s)he worked for that project. I don't see why that's not possible?

Comment: @Buffy So to rephrase, I'll issue them a bill at the end of each month, and it'll specify how many hours I've worked for them. Then they'll pay me that, at least this is how I'm thinking  of it.

Comment: Seems unlikely anywhere, anytime. I think you need a different plan.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks - but is there really no way to do academic research not being a part of formal academia, i.e. not holding an academic post? And I'm, not considering industrial R&D - did that before but the management is very different than academia and it wasn't a success for me. But I'm passionate by academic research, did it for long time and want to do it for the rest of my life. Isn't there really any way? If you prefer me to ask a different question, I can so you can answer if you know the answer.

Comment: @Buffy I'm only considering this options as a last resort if I don't end up securing a regular academic position; I'm in France and my visa/permit plays a role on the time constraint.

Comment: Anyone can do research as an "Independent researcher" and get it published. Especially in math. Harder in high energy physics if you need access to CERN. But academic affiliation isn't needed generally. And a freelancer isn't going to likely have that affiliation anyway if they are just your client.

Comment: @Buffy I agree with you on that - but I'm talking about getting pad in return for that research and that seems to be the problem. Yes, my subject being relatively theretical, I won't need machines like they do in physics

Comment: "So I'm imagining something like securing a project in say machine learning, with a faculty member who's a certain grant to hire researchers, but in place of hiring regular researchers, he can hire someone who'll bill him/the lab/department a certain amount that's a function of hours (s)he worked for that project." If the faculty member has a grant to hire researchers, why don't you apply to be one of the researchers they hire? Also I imagine you would already run into trouble with the grant agency disallowing the freelance aspect. Have you tried applying for grants yourself (national and eu)?

Comment: @Rammus Thanks for your comment!

I did apply for several such researcher's position, with non success yet. If they hire me, I'll be certainly on board. I don't known such faculty members. I've written to many, called many's offices, with zero response :(

Speaking about applying for grants, how can I do so? I'm out of a job at this moment, and have applied for a freelance position. I thought that the grants are written by professors or faculty members? Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @ScienceMan Postdocs can apply for grants also, e.g., Marie Curie. You probably need the support of a university or maybe even a faculty member when you submit but if you have a decent proposal then it shouldn't be too difficult to get the university/faculty member on board.

Comment: @Rammus Ah I see, yes I'm aware of these grants where you jointly submit a research proposal with a faculty member. Even if I was a postdoc thanks to one such proposal/grant at INRIA, France, my recent emails to faculty members saw no response. I've emailed several times and even called their offices, but heard no reply :(

Comment: @Rammus If you happen to know someone in France who can use my background in mathematics, statistical learning and geometry, I'd be grateful if you could help me cnnect with that person.

Comment: I find this question very relevant. In the end post-docs are treated somewhat like freelancers that work on a project for a certain amount of time. It should be possible to hire freelancers but unfortunately funding agencies have limitations that only allow certain contracts to pay people involved in the project. Post-docs in Europe should have a union.

Answer (score 3):

For most funding agencies, the organisation that applied for the funding is expected to conduct the funded work.  Outsourcing the work to a different organization, such as Freelance Science Man, without the permission of the funding agency *might* be grant fraud.

To get freelance research work that is funded by a funding agency, you would have to either:

- Convince the university to convince the funding agency to approve the freelance contract.  This is unlikely to work; if allowed, it's probably too much paperwork.
- Apply to the funding agency for funds directly, possibly with a university partner.  This does not strictly answer your question, and you probably will not want to do it because of the complex paperwork and risk involved.

Overall, I do not understand why you would want to freelance and postdoc at the same time, but if you really must do this, I suggest you get an ordinary postdoc job and hire a lawyer to figure out how to make your freelance business legal.

Comment: Note that freelance contractors and hourly employees are not the same thing under some legal systems.

Comment: If your expertise was in higher education management consulting, you might have better luck because the funding could come from teaching, and not a research funding agency.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer - upvoted! Now to your question: "Overall, I do not understand why you would want to freelance and postdoc at the same time", the short answer is that I need money (considering my age, previous work history and other factors irrelevant here) and a plan that'd allow me to be a freelance on top of that postdoc. And I'm already a declared freelance here in France with paperwork to prove it, and so I simply don't want to let that source of income go once I receive a postdoc offer.

Comment: If your main goal is to get money, being a postdoc is not the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: I did never say that it was my main goal, perhaps I conveyed myself incorrectly. My backstory is that: I switched to industry after a few postdocs, and that didn't turn out to be a success, nor they were places I belonged to. This made me realize two things: i) I belong to academia (80% of the professors/CNRS researchers I talked to said my CV was outstanding for a postdoc position, and only later I understood that my true place is academic research), and ii) during my years of failure in industry, I lost money, I've to make up for that. Freelance work and subcontracting may help with this.

Answer (score 3):

Definitively, it's possible in Spain, at least in some cases - I've done it twice.

In two projects I participated, the rules allowed for contracting external services. At least one of them was privately funded, so basically the funding entity (and the letter of the contracts) was mostly concerned with getting useful results. For several reasons, it was more convenient to hire a researcher as a contractor than as an employee.

I did that at a predoctoral level, but I've seen a similar case with a doctor.

In case anybody wonders, at least in one case the convenience reasons were more about my convenience than about those of the sponsor, the PI or the university.

Comment: The OP ended asking "in France or abroad". I tried a partial answer to the "abroad" part.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot - it's a partial relief and I'm glad to know that the possibility exists in Spain, I'm sure there should be something similar in France as well. What area did your do your postdoc in question in?

Comment: Not postdoc but sort of predoc - although I think it didn't matter a lot. I did it in biology and ecology, but I think it depends more on specific project conditions than on area.

Comment: While the answer to "is it possible" may be "yes", I think the likelihood of finding such an arrangement is vanishingly small. Don't arrange your career so as to depend on such unusual opportunities.